# jqgrid on cell click

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

How to display another jqgrid by selecting a cell on main jqgrid?I use local data to display values in the grid

Any links or tutorials will be of much help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to the demo of jqgrid
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

at the navigation menu expand advanced and click master detail and there will be a working demo you can see